# Qbasic reading comport reply without newline

Tags: reply, qbasic

I'm working on reading device reply using QBasic. The problem is the qbasic wait for the newline or CHR$(13) before outputting the data but my device reply don't have CHR$(13) (example: "OK") so qbasic hang waiting for newline.

How can i get the reply or read comport even without newline? is this possible?

**[EDIT]**

```
    CLS
     OPEN "com2:9600,n,8,1,BIN,cs,ds,rs" FOR RANDOM AS #1
    param$ ="Some data"
     PRINT #1, param$
      DO WHILE b$ <> "*CLOSE*"
       INPUT #1, b$
       PRINT b$
     LOOP
```

That is my code but in that code it can't read `*CLOSE*` because no newline after `*CLOSE*`.

And another thing the device delay 5 sec before replying.

Answer (score 1):

Could you give an example of your code? I suspect you are using `INPUT#n` , but maybe instead you should use `INPUT$(x)`. I found an [example here](http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/zines/qbcm/1-modem.html), see code below

```
a$ = ""
DO
IF LOC(1) THEN a$ = a$ + INPUT$(1, 1)
LOOP UNTIL INSTR(a$, "OK")
```

Comment: I simple use

` INPUT #1, data$
PRINT data$  `

Answer (score 0):

This code sample demonstrates accessing modem in Basic.

```
REM Reset modem source:
CLS
OPEN "COM2:9600,N,8,1,BIN,CS,DS,RS" FOR RANDOM AS #1
Reset$ = "ATZ" + CHR$(13) + CHR$(10)
PRINT #1, Reset$;
Inp$ = ""
DO
    IF LOC(1) THEN
        Inp$ = Inp$ + INPUT$(1, 1)
        IF INSTR(Inp$, "OK") THEN
            PRINT "Modem reset."
            EXIT DO
        END IF
    END IF
LOOP
END
```